# How do you pause and resume NewRelic transaction

Tags: php, laravel, newrelic

For a particular endpoint in my Laravel-based web app, on top of doing some internal processing, I need to communicate with a 3rd party service. I do not want to track the time taken to get response from the 3rd party service in my NewRelic (NR) transaction stats, but still want the time taken for all the internal processing stuffs.

Is there a way that can "pause" NR recording when the code reaches the 3rd party part and "resume" afterwards?

I've tried using `newrelic_end_transaction` and `newrelic_start_transaction` but it doesn't seem to be doing what I wanted.

Comment: Just to be clear (and I thought the question was clear enough), I am looking for a way to do this programatically (and not manually meddle with NR settings through their dashboard or turn off/ on my web server)

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the transaction that is calling the external service using the agent API

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/php-agent/php-agent-api/newrelic_ignore_transaction

Comment: Unfortunately I don't wanna ignore the entire transaction but only the external service portion.

Answer (score -1):

If you’d like to temporarily disable(pause) recording, it’s easiest to turn it off in the browser settings:

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/browser/new-relic-browser/installation-configuration/browser-settings-ui-options-browser-monitoring#disabling

This will cause your agent to restart in the background, and the new agent runs will not serve the script. However, if you use caching in your application, those caches may still need to be cleared before you see the effect of your change.

Answer (score -1):

If its a PHP application then

To disable the PHP agent, set the enabled config setting to false, then restart the web server or PHP.
After you disable the agent, it may take several minutes for data to stop showing up.

In any platform it involves modification in config file parameters such as
Set agentEnabled to false

Let me know if this works.